# how to come under “notes and attachments” of a contact record

Tags: upload

I have to upload an attachment of formats like (text) files from an external source  to the salesforce org, it has to come under “notes and attachments” of a contact record.Any body can u let me the Advance thanks

Comment: Please let me know any body ASAP

Answer (score 1):

you can insert the attachment record. here is the basic syntax.

```
Attachment at = new Attachment;
at.parentid= contact.id;
at.name='Sample Document';
at.ContentType='txt';
at.Body = Blob.valueOf(YOURCONTENTSTRING);
insert at;
```

Comment: Can u let me know briefly @ Himanshu

Comment: what else you want to know. I have already posted the code. replace the contact.id with your contact id. and YOURCONTENTSTRING with content.

Comment: The normal (MIME/Content) type for text is "text/plain".